# Why do you check for savedInstanceState == null when adding fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the fragment [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), in one of the example, they check for `savedInstanceState == null` when adding a fragment:

```
public static class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
                == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
            // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of this check? What would happen if it is not there?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> What is the purpose of this check?

To not add the fragment twice, though I prefer checking to see if the fragment is there instead of relying on that `Bundle` being `null`.

> What would happen if it is not there?

Initially, nothing, as the `Bundle` will be `null` when the activity is *first* created.

However, then, the user rotates the device's screen from portrait to landscape. Or, the user changes languages. Or, the user puts the device into a manufacturer-supplied car dock. Or, the user does any other configuration change.

Your activity will be destroyed and recreated by default. Your fragments will also be destroyed and recreated by default (exception: those on which `setRetainInstance(true)` are called, which are detached from the old activity and attached to the new one).

So, the *second* time the activity is created -- the instance created as a result of the configuration change -- your fragment *already exists*, as it was either recreated or retained. You don't want a second instance of that fragment (usually), and therefore you take steps to detect that this has occurred and not run a fresh `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: but even though when the activity is recreated the fragment already exists, don't you still have to "re-add" it to the activity somehow? Or is that done automatically when the fragment is recreated?

Comment: @Chin: It is done automatically when the fragment is recreated (or retained).

Comment: Is savedInstanceState guaranteed to be non-null even if your app doesn't save anything to it in onSaveInstanceState()? The doc on Activity.onCreate() says: "savedInstanceState Bundle: If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null."

Comment: @Phil: That bit of documentation lines up with what we have seen, that the parameter passed to `onCreate()` on `Activity` will be `null` for first creation and non-`null` (though possibly empty) on re-creation after configuration change and related events. I have never seen it behave otherwise.