# NavigationView with DrawerLayout setCheckedItem not working

Tags: android, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I want let `NavigationView` check one item when app startup. But i found `NavigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.xxx)` not working. And i also tried `navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.xxx).setChecked(true)`, same result.

I've already set checkableBehavior to single.

```
<item android:title="@string/sliding_menu_group_places">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/xxx" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/xxx" />

                ...
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

But there is one way worked:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            navigationView.setChecked(R.id.xxx);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        }
    });
```

The navigation item would be checked in onDrawerOpened callback. I've searched a lot in stackoverflow but none methods work for me. Who can help me about this.

**EDIT-1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
        android:title="@string/recent_display_name" />

    <item android:title="@string/sliding_menu_group_places">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/my_files_display_name" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_item_sdcard"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_sdcard"
                    android:title="@string/storage_display_name" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/sliding_menu_group_tool">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/clean_display_name" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/sliding_menu_group_settings">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/settings_display_name" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/exit_display_name" />
            </group>

        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Comment: try navigationView.getMenu().getItem(pos).setChecked(true);

Comment: just set , android:checked="true" inside your <item
                    android:id="@+id/xxx"
                    android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                    android:title="@string/xxx" /> . no need to set it manually in your java file.

Comment: mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true); here mDrawerList is you ListView, try this

Comment: @darwin still not working

Comment: is ur drawer listener works fine? try calling navigationView.getMenu().getItem(pos).setChecked(true); from anywere else

Comment: @darwin call `navigationView.getMenu().getItem(pos).setChecked(true)` in drawer listener works fine, but not working in other places.

Comment: @darwin You can see my edit-1 for menu's xml.

Comment: may be ur navigation view not ready while u are calling the setChecked

Comment: @darwin Yeah, I test it according to ur guess. Call `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.xxx);` after delay 2s, it's working. But i can't figure out why and how to solve it.

Comment: u may try calling it in onCreateOptionMenu() or OnPrepareOptionMenu(),but i am not sure it will work,i didn't tried this before

Comment: @darwin You can see my answer for detail. I solved by call `navigationView.post()`. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @darwin.

**Reason:**
`navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.xxx)` not working because the `NavigationView` isn't ready for it.

**Solution:**

```
navigationView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It worked! How is it possible that NavigationView is not ready?

Answer (score 2):

Menu items must be checkable.

```
<item android:title="@string/sliding_menu_group_places">
    <menu>
        <group> <!-- removed behavior -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/xxx"
                android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                android:title="@string/xxx"
                android:checkable="true" /> <!-- added 'checkable' -->

            <item
                android:id="@+id/xxx"
                android:icon="@drawable/xxx"
                android:title="@string/xxx"
                android:checkable="true" /> <!-- added 'checkable' -->

            ...
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this line of code with `itemChecked` is the index of the menu selected

```
 navigationView.getMenu().getItem(itemChecked).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
 menuItem.setCheckable(true);
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                if (mPreviousMenuItem != null && mPreviousMenuItem != menuItem) {
                    mPreviousMenuItem.setChecked(false);
                }
                mPreviousMenuItem = menuItem;
```

Comment: Thanks anyway bro, but this not the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following code open first fragment of NavigationView and check it on NavigationView. For meaning of **savedInstancesState == null** condition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26855936/4606368

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                Fragment fragment = new EventsUpcoming();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "Upcoming").commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_eventupcoming);
                toolbar.setTitle(R.string.events_upcoming);
}
```

Add this code in OnCreate method of your activity.

Answer (score -1):

use `setChecked` method of item instead of `navigationView`

```
navigationView.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
   }
});
```