# How to use a ViewModel correctly in Android?

Tags: android

Everytime my activity is destroyed and  oncreate is called, the getUserDetails function from viewModel gets executed which again performs a network call in repository. The whole idea of a viewModel is to persist data when configuration changes. Which I am not able to achieve here

Following is my viewmodel code:

```kotlin
class LoginViewModel(repository: UserRepository): ViewModel() {
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User>
    get() = _user

    fun getUserDetails(userId: String) {
       viewModelScope.launch {
         _user.postValue(repository.getUserDetails(userId))
       }
       
    }
}
```

Activity Code:

```kotlin
onCreate() {
   viewModel.user.observe {
     myAction()
   }

   viewModel.getUserDetails(intent.extras.getString(IntentConstants.USER_ID.name))
}
```

Comment: There are different approaches: 
1) In this case, when you want one time network call, you can do it in 'init {} ' so after configuration changing, it won't be called anymore. You can pass 'userId' parameter in constructor.

2) You can check if(savedInstancestate == null) viewModel.getUserDetails(id) 
    in onCreate()

Comment: I think is responsability of your repository to perform a network call or use data alredy stored in your cache or db, the logic should be in the repository, your code is ok to me.

Comment: ViewModel remains memory until the Lifecycle destroys permanently. For 

`Activity`- When it finish 
`Fragment`- When it detached 

So it's simple, whenever your activity is created and you invoke your network call then it's obvious to get call to your view-model.

Check ViewModel scope with lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-lifecycle.png).

You have to create the Repository to get data from Network calls or from the local cache. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide)

Comment: Also, you can pass an instance of `LifecycleOwner` which is available with each `Fragment` and `Activity` when using the `observe` method on the `LiveData` value being sent by the `ViewModel` and consumed by the respective view

Answer (score 0):

I already had some hints on checking the savedInstancestate == null, and when I searched why do we need savedInstanceState check, it really helped me out.

Thank you @Nika Chapizade for your comment.

If savedInstanceState is null in the activity, then the onCreate is called the first time. And whenever a configuration change would occur it would not be null when onCreate is called. As specified here: [Why do you check for savedInstanceState == null when adding fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855848/why-do-you-check-for-savedinstancestate-null-when-adding-fragment)

So the ideal way in my scenario to do it would be:

```kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
   fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       if(savedInstanceState == null) {
     viewModel.getUserDetails(intent.extras.getString(IntentConstants.USER_ID.name))
       }
       viewModel.user.observe(this, Observer {
          myAction()
       })
   }
}
```

So whenever a configuration change happens it won't ask for new data, but it would observe it and then whatever's the last value in the user livedata it will emit it.